# Sourcemap examples

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, source-maps

I'm trying to teach myself and potentially others how to use sourcemaps, so I made an example via a Gruntfile.

```
coffee:
  options:
    sourceMap: true
  app1:
    files:
      'app1.js': 'app1.coffee'
  app2:
    files:
      'app2/app2.js': 'app2/app2.coffee'

uglify:
  app1:
    options:
      sourceMap: 'app1.map'
      sourceMapIn: 'app1.js.map'
    files:
      'app1.min.js': 'app1.js'
  app2:
    options:
      sourceMap: 'app2/app2.map'
      sourceMapIn: 'app2/app2.js.map'
      sourceMappingURL: '../app2/app2.js.map'
    files:
      'app2/app2.min.js': 'app2/app2.js'
```

If you go to http://webjay.github.io/sourcemaps/ in Chrome and open the console and click on app1.coffee you will see the sourcecode line correctly.

But if you click on app2.coffee, which is in a subfolder, you will see the correct sourcecode file but will not be taken to the correct line.
Why and how can I fix that?

My repository is at [GitHub](https://github.com/webjay/sourcemaps) and feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the network tab `app2.js.map` returns a 404. Is this because of your leading slash? (sourceMappingURL)

```
  app2:
    options:
      sourceMap:        'app2/app2.map'
      sourceMapIn:      'app2/app2.js.map'
      sourceMappingURL: '/app2/app2.js.map'
```

Comment: Weird, it's there: https://raw.github.com/webjay/sourcemaps/gh-pages/app2/app2.js.map
Perhaps a GitHub limit?

Comment: What I mean is that sourceMappingURL has a leading slash where the others don't, is this what is causing your problem?

Comment: No I don't think so. I'll investigate the 404.

Comment: Just tested locally, with no 404, same problem.

Comment: sorry, you're right, the 404 is caused by the /, but it didn't solve my question.

Comment: OK, can you just try changing that source mapping URL to 'app2.js.map' so that rules that out?

Comment: Done, no 404, but same problem.

Comment: Looking at this (http://webjay.github.io/sourcemaps/app2/app2.min.js) I think it might be the sourceMapIn that causes the problem.